# PHP convert string to another Timezone when day has 2 digits

Tags: php, datetime, timezone

i get a date time in string using webscraping.its in Berlin time zone and i want to convert it to Moscow time.

i do it as below :

```
$date_str ="7/4/2019 3:30";
  try {
      $date = new DateTime($date_str, new DateTimeZone('Europe/Berlin'));
      $date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('Europe/Moscow'));
      $date_in_moscow = $date->format('d/m/Y H:i');
  } catch (Exception $e) {
       echo "error";
  }
```

when day in $date_str has one digit like "7" (without zero),evrething will be ok.but when day has 2 digit lik "17" , catch block get called.
i tried with using ('j/n/Y H:i') as format,but result was same.
i do not know why?!is it because of format type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue that you are facing is due to the fact that you are using a date string in **d/m/Y** format while the `DateTime::__construct` expects it in **m/d/Y** format.

In order to bypass this issue you need to change the function call as following:

```
$date_str ="13/4/2019 13:30";
try {
    $date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y H:i', $date_str, new DateTimeZone('Europe/Berlin'));
    $date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('Europe/Moscow'));
    echo $date_in_moscow = $date->format('d/m/Y H:i');
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "error";
}
```

Comment: that is exactly what i want ,complete and right answer

Comment: Glad that I could help.

Answer (score 0):

change format $date_str to "m/d/Y H:i" like "7/17/2019 3:30"

Comment: @Zima, you do not need to change the date format for this to work.